# Android: Switching from 2nd activity back to 1st quits both

Tags: android, android-activity

The solution to this problem was pretty simple:

Unfortunatly i somehow commented this wrong in my code, maybe i copied it from somewhere:

```
public void onUserLeaveHint() { // this only executes when Home is selected.
        if(started){
            started=false;
            recordTask.cancel(true);
            }
            this.finish();
            super.onUserLeaveHint();
        }
    }
}
```

Thats from the API:

> Called as part of the activity lifecycle when an activity is about to go into the background as the result of user choice.

So whenever a new activity is started, the main went in background and was finished.

Thanks for help to all anyway. Stupid fault of mine, simply forgot about that method.
Problem solved.

Original Question:

I reduced the code of the second activity to only give a result back for now, it looks like this.
(The second activity works when i uncomment the whole code. Its just a file explorer, which should give String path back. For debugging i use this untill i can get it to work.)
Both activities are declared in the manifest.

```
public class AndroidExplorer extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.olddata);

        Intent sender=getIntent();
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("ComingFrom", "Hello");
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        AndroidExplorer.this.finish();
    }
}
```

This is called from the first activity by:

```
Intent intent;
intent = new Intent(firstactivity.this,AndroidExplorer.class);
firstactivity.this.startActivityForResult(intent,0);
```

And the result should be recieved by:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
    {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     String extraData=data.getStringExtra("ComingFrom");
     Log.e("result", extraData);
     go2startscreen();
    }
```

Unfortunatly it wont return to the first activity, it just closes the app.

Error Log:

```
04-26 11:11:14.096: D/memalloc(32383): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51b3e000 size:17645568 offset:15556608 fd:53
04-26 11:11:32.264: D/memalloc(32383): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52e66000 size:3686400 offset:1597440 fd:59
04-26 11:11:32.584: D/memalloc(32383): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x51b3e000 size:17645568 offset:15556608
04-26 11:11:32.584: D/memalloc(32383): /dev/pmem: Unmapping buffer base:0x52e66000 size:3686400 offset:1597440
04-26 11:11:32.644: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32383): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-26 11:11:32.644: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(32383): InputConnection = android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection@40d9ddd0, active client = false
```

And here is the go2startscreen function:

```
void go2startscreen(){
        setContentView(R.layout.startscreen);
        appPosition = "startscreen";
        newRecord = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.newRecord);
        newRecord.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

So it should end at R.layout.startscreen. Calling go2startscreen works, when i call it from the first activity.

Comment: can you post go2startscreen() function ?

Comment: Could be a lot of things, can you post the log from DDMS? Could be something as simple as not declaring one of the activities in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: I just edited the question. Starting the second activity works. I declared it in the manifest. Error Logs come in a second.

Comment: What if you don't call `super.onActivityResult()`?

Comment: do you never call finish() on firstactivity, do you?

Comment: @Jonas same thing: app closes

Comment: @blackbelt no finish in first activity

Comment: @Akki i call go2startscreen, because the app should go there after returning from the second activity :D, anyway it doesnt matter, if i comment go2startscreen() out it still just closes

Comment: @Akki: could you be more precise on that ? I dont get what you mean.

Comment: I have different contentviews for every Page in my main activity. I do something on first contentview then go to second. Id have done it by this way to implement the file browser thing, but as it needs "extends ListActivity" i had to create a activity for that. Anyway i dont think that it is the problem, as it would throw an error if there would be something wrong with the contentview.

Comment: A little addon: i never really learned JAVA but only C++. So this app is mainly based on functions/methods and a main class :S

Comment: as said before i tried that, it still just closes

Comment: @user1222353 firstactivity extends which class?

Comment: @Akki "public class Test extends Activity implements OnClickListener"

Comment: same: wont go back to first activity

Comment: Please move extended discussions to [chat] when possible.

Comment: Question answered, see OP. Cant answer my own question.

Answer (score 1):

Check resultCode if its ok then do what u want--like this::

```
@Override
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode,Intent data)
   {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
    String extraData=data.getStringExtra("ComingFrom");
    Log.e("result", extraData);
   go2startscreen();
    }
  }
```

Hope it will help you..

Comment: no Log for that, i even tried with Log.e("res",""+resultCode) before the if statement